# Tar file downloaded in Perl, corrupts the UTF8 (and file)

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure out what is going on here. I have the following code:

```
# compress and force a download of the .zip
`cd /srv/www/domain.net/www/cgi-bin/admin/amazon_template_tmp/; tar -cvvf files.tar *`;

my $filepath = '/srv/www/domain.net/www/cgi-bin/admin/amazon_template_tmp/files.tar';
my $file = \do { local *FH; *FH };
open $file, "<$filepath" or die "Unable to open file '$filepath': $!";
binmode $file;
binmode STDOUT;

print $IN->header($IN->file_headers(
    filename => "csv_files.tar",
    mimetype => 'application/gzip',
    inline   => 0,
    size     => -s $filepath
));

{
    local $\;
    while (read($file, my $chunk, 4096)) {
        print $chunk;
    }
}
```

This tells the script to compress that folder into a .tar file, and then to grab it and download. There are a couple of issues:

1) If I compared the file (downloaded via FTP), to the one my script is downloading (via the browser), I get corrupt utf8 characters:

(oops, I have these the wrong way around - as noted by someone :))
[image]

2) The downloaded file (via the browser), opens in WinRar - but it only includes the first file (and not all of that either). There error I get is:

> !   C:\Users\Andy\AppData\Local\Temp\csv_files-1.tar: The archive is
>   corrupt

Can someone point me in the right direction? I thought I had all the `binmode` / `STDOUT` stuff set up right, so I'm a bit confused!

**As an update:** The following is the headers that are being passed along to the browser:

```
Content-type: application/gzip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="csv_files.tar"; size=71680
Content-Length: 71680
```

I've also tried this method for printing the contents:

```
open FILE, "< $filepath" or die "can't open : $!";
binmode FILE;
local $/ = \10240;
while (<FILE>){
    print $_;
}
close FILE;
```

Still not joy though. I'm almost at the point of giving up, and just doing a `Location:` redirection to the file, so the browser downloads it that way (this is only an admin backend tool, which is why I can read the file even though its in the cgi-bin)

Comment: I cannot understand how your code is supposed to work. Does it matter that `$filepath` is different from the path in the `cd` command? (`domainnet` vs. `domain.net`). Where is the "download" happening? What manner of thing is `$IN`? The line `my $file = \do { local *FH; *FH }` is very strange, and the same result would be achieved by writing `open my $file, '<', $filepath ...`

Comment: @Borodin - sorry, the first was a typo (its actually my domain, but I replaced it in the sample code).  Do you have an example with the other code suggested? I've used the `{ local $\; while (read($file, my $chunk, 4096)) { xxxx } }` method quite a few times before - but its been with PDF files, and not tar files. `$IN` is just a perl module (based on CGI.pm) I believe), so all that line is doing is printing out the headers

Comment: @Borodin - I've also updated the OP to show the headers bring printed out via the `$IN->header()` part

Comment: So is this CGI code running on an HTTP server?

Comment: @Borodin - Yes. Its an nxingx server, with a reverse proxy to Apache2. FWIW, I just tried manually loading https://sample.net/cgi-bin/admin/amazon_template_tmp/files.tar, and it downloads and opens the file fine. I could do that as an alternative, but I would prefer to know whats up with my code :)

Comment: Also, just out of interest I tried `application/octet-stream` as the MIME-Type - but this doesn't help

Comment: You're setting the output record separator to UNDEF.  I've always seen slurping done with the input record separator $/ set to UNDEF.

Comment: @charlesbridge - thanks. Not sure what you mean? I've updated my OP with an extra example that I tried, which I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294815/perl-cgi-to-download-a-file-via-web-browser - doesn't seem to work either though (same issue with corrupt contents)

Comment: @charlesbridge:  Like a lot of this code, that's certainly wrong but it doesn't matter. `$\ ` is `undef` by default anyway, and calls to `read` are independent of the value of the record separator.

Comment: @AndrewNewby: Are the files that download okay with FTP the *same files* that are generated by the tar command in your CGI code? Or do you create them differently as well as download them differently? I'm wondering why one is call `files.tar` and the other is `csv_files.tar`.

Comment: @Bodrin - they are the exact same files. This is driving me nuts! As a test, I just copied the contents of de.csv into de.txt. I then changed it to ONLY compress the .txt files. If I remove some of the contents, it works fine. If I remove some of the content, it works fine. If I add in some basic ASCII, like: `dfsdfsdfsfsdfg dgfdf gdfg dfg dffgdfgdfg`  ...it works BUT when you get to a certain point (around the 16kb point it seems), it then says the file is corrupt! ARGH. I think I'm just going to do the `Location:` download, as this is driving me nuts!

Comment: @AndrewNewby: I can pretty much see what's going wrong, but I'm confused about the displays that you're showing. What is the utility that you're using there? The image of `csv_files.tar` on the left is showing the ISO-8859-1 representation of the UTF-8 encoding of the characters in `files.tar` on the right. But the status line of both screens says that it's interpreting both files as UTF-8. If that is true then the "correct" file on the left has been double-encoded, so that you see each byte of the encoded character as its own character. That's confusing. Tell me more about the display app.

Comment: Real programmers don't give up until they can pass the problem on to their children.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks. The file is exactly the same. Downloaded via FTP, and then downloaded via the script (using the above code). The md5sums are different on them though. I really don't have the time to fumble around with this :( The files on the server are showing  as `UTF-8 With BOM` ... and they show up fine. So do the files if  I download the tar via FTP, and then open it

Comment: A real programmer also knows when to call it quits, and find another solution ;)

Comment: @AndrewNewby: I will try to reproduce it tomorrow if I can find time. Is there any chance that you can give me a link to some of the CSV files that don't make it through, together with their corrupted tar files? I'd also like to see the code for the class behind `$IM`. It's all down to UTF-8 encoding somehow and there's nothing related to that in the code that you've shown.

Comment: @AndrewNewby:  And again, what's the app you're using to display the data?

Comment: @Borodin thanks. The $IN stuff is tricky, as its a custom module that comes with the CMS I'm using (Gossamer Links), so I can't give out that code as its pay-for software. If you can email me on andy dot newby@ gmnail dot com, and I'll send you the files.  They are my amazon stores CSV files, so I don't really want them public :)

Comment: @Borodin - I got it :) Turns out there was something in $IN that was printing utf8 to STDIN, which I guess is what we screwing it up. Thanks for sticking with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I'm not too sure what is going on, but I managed to get it working. I took out the function that prints the headers:

```
print $IN->header($IN->file_headers(
    filename => "csv_files.tar",
    mimetype => 'application/x-download',
    inline   => 0,
    size     => -s $filepath
));
```

and just replaced it with my own simple headers:

```
print qq|Content-type: application/x-download\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename="csv_files.tar"\n\n|;
```

I wonder if it has something to do with this in the $IN module:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

Comment: Absolutely. `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")` will encode the data into UTF-8, treating each byte as if it were a single character. That will *double-encode* data if it is already encoded, as I suggested. But that makes the *left-hand* image the faulty one. Did you get them mixed up? It's certainly the one that *looks* wrong.

Comment: @Borodin - haha yes, you are correct - I had them mixed up in the WinMerge compare window. It'd been one of those days!

Comment: AndrewNewby: So you don't show the piece of code where the problem is *and* you swap the good and bad versions of the data! Didn't stand a chance really, did we! :)

Comment: @Borodin - the problem was with this: `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");`, in the GT::CGI module (i.e $IN). Because I changed from using `print $IN->header($IN->file_headers(....))` to just a basic  version - ie `print qq|Content-type: application/x-download\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename="csv_files.tar"\n\n|;`, this got around the issue (as $IN->header isn't called now, and thats where the extra unwanted header was being printed :))