# Downloading a file from web using Perl CGI.pm

Tags: perl

I am trying to write Perl script to download a file from web and then processing it. I have only `CGI.pm` installed in my server space. Please kindly advise.

Comment: There's also the core [File::Fetch](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Fetch) module.

Comment: Please check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294815/perl-cgi-to-download-a-file-via-web-browser

Answer (score 1):

I think you're slightly confused. If you're trying to download a file, then CGI.pm will be no use to you. CGI.pm helps you to write CGI programs; it has nothing to help you download files.

To download a file from a web server, you need something that acts as a web client. A browser is a web client, but we need a program that acts like that - sending an HTTP request and processing the HTTP response.

The most obvious option is [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple). This includes a function called `getstore()`.

```
my $code = getstore($url, $file);
```

You say that this isn't available to you. In order to write Perl programs of any complexity, you should find a place to host them that gives you access to lots of Perl modules (or allows you to install them). So much of modern Perl programming consists of joining together functions from CPAN modules and by not having access to that, you are seriously curtailing the options that are available to you.

But there are a couple of other options that are part of the standard Perl distribution and should be available to you.

[HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) has been part of the core Perl distribution since Perl 5.14 in 2011. You could use its `mirror()` function to download your file.

[File::Fetch](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Fetch) has been part of the Perl code distribution since Perl 5.10 in 2007. You could use it like this:

```
use File::Fetch;

my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $your_uri);
# $where will contain the path to the downloaded file
my $where = $ff->fetch or die $ff->error;
```

Comment: Thank u friend.I am using free web hoisting by Tripod.com.The perl version used in the server is 5.8 or so.The available perl modules(.pm) in the cgi-bin directory are CGI.pm.TripodCGI.pm,TripodPage.pm .I would like know whether any of this module can be used for down loading a file. Also how can I know the functions exported by these modules ?.Any other alternative to down load file with the old perl version ?

Comment: @jose: As I said, CGI.pm has absolutely nothing to do with downloading files and I'm not sure why you would think it does. The Tripod modules are non-standard and I know nothing about them - so you would need to ask Tripod. But it seems to me that the Tripod hosting is targeted at people wanting to write web applications. And that's not what you want at all. Why not install Strawberry Perl (http://strawberryperl.com/) on your PC and use that? Or, perhaps better, use WSL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) and get a full Linux experience.

Comment: @jose: Perl 5.8 is from 2002. It is old enough to vote. Anyone who gives you a version of Perl that is as old as that does not care about Perl developers. So I'd really recommend looking elsewhere if you're going to be using Perl.

Comment: Ok sir.Please comment on this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294815/perl-cgi-to-download-a-file-via-web-browser

Comment: @jose: That is about writing a web app that will **send** a file to a user's browser. You said you wanted a program that will **download** a file from a web server. Those are two very different things. You need to be clear what you want.

Comment: Actualy I want to down load data from a google sheet and process it using perl and producing  a web page

Comment: @jose: So you can use CGI.pm to create the web page containing the data. But in order to access the Google Sheet, you will need one of the modules I've discussed in my answer. You should seriously consider getting better hosting.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point for you is to use [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple)

Comment: Thank u.But I would like to use CGI.pm as i have access only to that module.I am using Tripods free web uploading